# webpack dev server doesn't run piz help me

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

my webpack dev sercer doesn't run piz help my

my err :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80mph.png)

webpack config

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase:  path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/app.js'),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        watchContentBase: true
    }
```

package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack serve"
  },


"devDependencies": {
    "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config is no longer supported in webpack version 5

try this

```js
{
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static:  {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/app.js')
        },
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        watch: true
    }
}
```

for more details you can look at [dev-server documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server)